# Enable nested comments in Theme

Tags: comment-form, comments, comments-template, pingbacks

I am trying to enable nested comments in my theme. I am new to all this stuff but I am doing my best. This is the code that I have in my comments.php

```
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'triday' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '← Older Comments', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments →', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
    <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
             * to use triday_comment() to format the comments.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then you can
             * define triday_comment() and that will be used instead.
             * See triday_comment() in inc/template-tags.php for more.
             */
            wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'triday_comment' ) );
        ?>
    </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'triday' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '← Older Comments', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments →', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
    <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

<!--</div>-->
<?php endif; // have_comments() ?>
```

This is the code that I use to display the comments

```
<div class="comment-author">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php print(' ')?><?php comment_author( $comment_ID ); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                                <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'triday' ); ?></p>
                                </div>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <?php comment_text(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .comment-content -->
                            <div class="comment-metadata">
                                <a>comment_ID ) ); ?>">
                                    <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                                        <p class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i> <?php printf( _x( '%1$s at %2$s', '1: date, 2: time', 'triday' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ); ?></p>
                                    </time>
                                </a>

                                <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'triday' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                            </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->
                            <footer class="comment-meta">
                        </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->
                        <?php
                            comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
                                'add_below' => 'div-comment',
                                'depth'     => $depth,
                                'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
                                'before'    => '<div class="reply">',
                                'after'     => '</div>',
                            ) ) );
                        ?>
```

I would really be glad if you could take a look at what I've done! 
Hannes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Settings >> Discussion Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_Screen), there is a options tick box, 'Enable threaded (nested) comments [X] levels deep'. From there you can tick to activate threaded comments and set how many levels deep to a maximum of 10.

You should also check if your theme has the following piece of code, should normally be in the functions.php template of your theme.

```
wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply')
```

This will enqueue the script to properly display the threaded comments. I quote from the codex

> Note that themes need to be specially coded to properly display
>   threaded comments.

If not found, you can simply add the following code to your functions.php to enqueue this script. Please note, this script is included by default in the Wordpress core, so there is no need to look or add the script yourself.

```
function enable_threaded_comments(){
if (!is_admin()) {
     if (is_singular() && comments_open() && (get_option('thread_comments') == 1))
          wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
     }
}

add_action('get_header', 'enable_threaded_comments');
```

(Code from [paulund.co.uk](http://www.paulund.co.uk/))

**EDIT**

There are a couple of errors in your code. I have tested your first set of code. There is a syntax error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\pietergoosen2014\comments.php
>   on line 30

This means you have an extra `endif;`, so just remove that

In your comments you asked

> Do you know why I get an id when I press the reply link, like this -
>
> `http://localhost:8888/testar and`
>
> `http://localhost:8888/testar/?replytocom=9#respond`

Yes, you forgot to make the call to `comment_form();`

So your code in comments.php should look like this

```
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'triday' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '← Older Comments', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments →', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
    <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
             * to use triday_comment() to format the comments.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then you can
             * define triday_comment() and that will be used instead.
             * See triday_comment() in inc/template-tags.php for more.
             */
             wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'triday_comment' ) );
            ?>

    </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'triday' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '← Older Comments', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments →', 'triday' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
    <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

<!--</div>-->
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have done what it as you said, unfortunately it is still not working. When I press the reply button I get an id in the URl but is as if the page was reload and you are not direct to the comments form. Is that as it is or is the reply link still not working? @PieterGoosen

Comment: You are using a customized theme from what I can see from your code. There should be a theme options page then, you will need to check the options set for comments. You should be able to select and change how comments are displayed there

Comment: I have tried to figure out what is wrong and I think I get a syntax now when trying to post a new comment. The problem is that there is no theme options page because I am trying to build the theme my self!

Comment: How can I make that threaded comments look differently and are placed inside of eachother? Is it only the css on thread-odd and stuff? @PieterGoosen

Comment: You can check out [this tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/2009/how-to-add-nested-comments-to-your-wordpress-theme/) about styling threaded comments

Comment: Thanks I checked it out and it exclude that is was the styling that wasn't enough. Do you know why I get an id when I press the reply link, like this - `http://localhost:8888/testar` and `http://localhost:8888/testar/?replytocom=9#respond`

Comment: See my update. You should get this working now

Comment: My pleasure. Glad your problem is solved

Comment: I have the snippet of code you recommend and it still isn't working quite right. I switched form DISQUS which is now blocked in China to native WordPress comments my existing threaded comments work, but when I try to add a new threaded comment it doesn't behave as expected.